# Isotope, absolute position of items not correct on when resizing window

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I have a Isotope layout which works fine but when I resize the window it positions the item wrong. In my case it adds 'left:20px' making the first item stick out to the left(it's always the first item that is positioned wrong). The thing is it doesn't happen consistently, sometimes it resizes with the good position and sometimes with the bad position, I absolutely have clue what causes this at all.

This is the correct layout before resizing things
[image: eded here]

This what sometimes happens after resizing, it sometimes just adds left:20px to to the first element for I don't know what reason. 
[image]

This is my only javascript code:

```
var $container = $('.blog-container');
$container.imagesLoaded( function () {
    $('.blog-container').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item-blog'
    });
});
```

Here the actual [link](http://www.vita-gamer.com/ludens/) to experience it first hand.

This occurs when resizing under and above 1280

I'm really at the end and I very much appreciate any help!

Comment: There is a way in Masonry to center the items, I presume there is a similar feature in isotope (both desandro plugs) which I think will solve your issue - check the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I had put my isotope container in a div with the row class of Bootstrap, that was apparently messing up the isotope calculations I guess.
Now I removed the row class of Bootstrap and everything seems to work perfectly now.

I think, it's a done deal for now.